# Is there a way to embed Github hosted javascript in a script tag?

Tags: javascript, github

I've had someone submit a pull request for a Javascript library I've got hosted on Github. I'd like to test it in jsfiddle, but I'd like to keep my fiddle script window clean by NOT Copy/Pasting the entire library.

Is there a way to link to the file hosted on Github, and have it served as `Application/Javascript`?

Basically I want to wire up a very simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), and add the file hosted on Github as a resource under the "Add Resources" tab.

Comment: rough day... I'm struggling with writing an appropriate title for this question...

Comment: jsfiddle has a "Add Resources" section. Just put the URL to the raw file there or include a `script` tag in the HTML section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the "raw" URL of the file on GitHub.  To get this, click on the file you want, then click the "Raw" button.

Then, on jsFiddle on the left, click "Add Resources".  Paste the URL in the box and, click the plus sign.

Now jsFiddle will use your JS file from GitHub.